# Objeto que referência outro pode ser coletado?

Tags: php, memória, garbage-collector

A classe possui referências ao próximo objeto e ao objeto anterior (Lista). E possui um método para ser deletado

```
...
function delete(){
    if($this->previousColumn){
      $this->previousColumn->nextColumn = $this->nextColumn;
    }
    if(($this->previousRow)){
      $this->previousRow->nextRow = $this->nextRow;
    }
  }
...
```

Se eu não configurar os campos previous e next

```
...
public ?CellInfo $nextColumn, $nextRow,
 $previousColumn, $previousRow;
...
```

para `null` este objeto será coletado pelo lixeiro? Ou ele continuará existindo mesmo que nenhum outro objeto tenha referência a ele, mas ele tendo referência a outros objetos

Quando chamo delete os outros objetos da lista deixam de ter referência para o objeto, dessa forma, o código deixa de ter referência a ele.

Entretanto o objeto em que chamo delete ainda continua tendo referências a outros objetos

Então ele será coletado?

```
class CellInfo{
  public $x, $y;
  public $possible_values = [];
  public ?CellInfo $nextColumn = null, $nextRow = null;
  public ?CellInfo $previousColumn = null, $previousRow = null;
  public $is_unique;

  function addPossibleValue($value){
    $this->possible_value[] = $value;
  }
  function setNextColumn(CellInfo $ci){
    $this->nextColumn = $ci;
    $ci->previousColumn = $this;
  }
  function delete(){
    if($this->previousColumn){
      $this->previousColumn->nextColumn = $this->nextColumn;
      //Como $this->previousColumn não foi 
//cofigurado para null ele continuará tendo 
//referência a outro objeto, mas não terá
// mais referência dentro da lista
    }
    if(($this->previousRow)){
      $this->previousRow->nextRow = $this->nextRow;
    }
  }
}//*/
$t1 = new CellInfo();
$t1->x = 10;
$t2 = new CellInfo();
$t2->x = 15;
$t3 = new CellInfo();
$t3->x = 20;

$t1->setNextColumn($t2);
$t2->setNextColumn($t3);
//*/
$t2->delete();//O coletor irá coletar esse $t2?
```

Answer (score 1):

O *garbage collector* do PHP coleta um objeto quando ele não tem mais referências. Se você deixar apenas uma referência, não importa onde, o objeto não será coletado até o fim da execução, ou no momento que a referência deixe de existir explicitamente em alguma parte do código, ou implicitamente se a referência vem de um objeto que é destruído automaticamente por alguma razão, por exemplo quando esse `this` deixa de existir.

Isso é detalhe de implementação e pode mudar, mas normalmente ele tem um contador de referências. E se falhar por entrar em um ciclo ainda tem um coletor extra.

Eu não tenho como responder de forma mais precisa porque a pergunta fala em campos `previous` e `next` e em nenhum lugar do código tem campos com esses nomes. E também porque não há maior contexto.

De qualquer forma a pergunta mudou, o código nem faz o que fazia antes e n~]ao parece fazer muito sentido mais.

Mas está fazendo o que com PHP? *Scripts* no *backend* web? Se é isso então não precisa se preocupar, o *script* durará um tempo muito curto, alocará bem poucos objetos e mesmo que tudo falhe o fim dele coletará os objetos que ficarem.

Se está usando PHP para outra coisa que mantém o objetos vivos por muito tempo então deveria repensar a linguagem, PHP não foi feita pra isso. E quem me disse pessoalmente foi o criador da linguagem.

Comment: Eu só queria saber como ele funciona, já o campo previous e next é 'previous'Row next'Row' e column.